# Is it possible to have a nested MultipartEntities or FormBodyPart in a multipart POST?

Tags: android, apache, http, multipartentity

I'm trying to make something the following server POST request using MultipartEntity:

```
parameters: {"parameter1"=>"parameter1", "parameter2"=>{"sub_parameter1"=>"sub_parameter1", "sub_parameter2"=>"sub_parameter2"}}
```

I am currently using something like:

```
multipartEntity.addPart("parameter1", new StringBody("parameter1"));

FormBodyPart parameter2 = new FormBodyPart("parameter2", new StringBody("")); // It wouldn't allow a null ContentBody

parameter2.addField("sub_parameter1", "sub_parameter1");
parameter2.addField("sub_parameter2", "sub_parameter2");
```

However, the sub fields do not carry though. I just get:

```
parameters: {"parameter1"=>"parameter1", "parameter2"=>""}
```

How do I create a nested structure in either the MultipartEntity or the FormBodyPart elements it contains?

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: i am looking for something like this too but couldnot get it working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

once you've seen how the form entries are transferred over HTTP connection, you'll understand it's impossible to have anything nested with the multiform request as well as with the url-encoded request.

things are very simple. multipart form request has the format of:

```
--- content-boundary ---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_data_name"

[content (skipped)]
--- content-boundary ---
```

that's it. there's stream of single data form entries in the format: [form entry name] -> [form entry content] that repeats for every entry in the form. it's not recursive, therefore there may not be any nested structures.

Sources:

1. [17.13.4 Form content types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)
2. [RFC 2045 Internet Message Bodies](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)

Comment: It is a really nice solution and that, pretty much sums up that 'nested' is not a word for Multipart Entity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider sending a json in the body of the request. That way you can send whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("selectedGroup", new StringBody(group));
reqEntity.addPart("selectedService", new StringBody(service.toString()));
reqEntity.addPart("selectedTransformation", new StringBody(transformation.toString()));
reqEntity.addPart("projectId", new StringBody(projectId.toString()));
```

Check exapmle 8 of this link. Also exapmple 23
[Example Site](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity)

Hope this helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> why dont you post whole Json object instead of post each string value
>   of Json object.

Go through this link http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and I've ended up adjusting the code on my server side to remove parameter 2, in order to use MultipartEntity on the client side. It worked perfectly fine.

```
parameters: {"parameter1"=>"parameter1", "parameter2"=>{"sub_parameter1"=>"sub_parameter1", "sub_parameter2"=>"sub_parameter2"}}

parameters: {"parameter1"=>"parameter1", "sub_parameter1"=>"sub_parameter1", "sub_parameter2"=>"sub_parameter2"}
```