# Uploading a file in an array of object using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use Retrofit2 and I need to upload various files using `file` in an array of objects `Media` like this :

```
{
   "state" = "done",
   "medias" = [
     {
      "file" = THE_FILE1
     },
     {
      "file" = THE_FILE2
     },
     {
      "file" = THE_FILE3
     }
   ]
}
```

This is the function of my `Interface` :

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/exercice/{id}")
fun submitExercice(
    @Path("id") id: Int,
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Body data: AnswerExercice
): Call<Void>
```

And this is my object `Media` :

```
    data class AnswerExercice(
    val state: String = "done",
    val medias: List<Media>
) : Serializable {
    data class Media(
        @Part val file: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : Serializable
}
```

But I have this error :

> @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.
>   (parameter #3)

What am i not doing well?

This is what the API documentation say :
[image: tat]

The result have to be like this :
[image]

Comment: Check [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server) for multiple file upload using retrofit

Comment: Jéwôm' - what was wrong with Hussain's link? The link's example shows not to use @Body

Comment: This link don't show how to put a file in an array of object. The link show directly a list of MultipartBody.Part but I need an array of object "medias" containing the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**
If you like to send your data exactly like the structure you mentioned, you should convert files content to `Base64` and wrap them in a serializable class and post it as the body. Here is the sample of wrapper class:

```
data class AnswerExerciceBase64(val state: String, val medias: List<Media>) : Serializable

data class Media(val file: Base64File) : Serializable

class Base64File(file: File) : Serializable {

    val name: String
    val content: String

    init {
        name = file.name
        content = Base64.encodeToString(FileInputStream(file).readBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
}
```

And your `Api` is like this:

```
@POST("api/exercice/{id}")
fun submitExercice(
        @Path("id") id: Int,
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Body data: AnswerExerciceBase64
): Call<Void>
```

Then posted data to server will be like below:

```
{
    "state": "this is state",
    "medias": [{
        "file": {
            "content": "Base64 file content",
            "name": "f1.txt"
        }
    }, {
        "file": {
            "content": "Base64 file content",
            "name": "f2.txt"
        }
    }, {
        "file": {
            "content": "Base64 file content",
            "name": "f3.txt"
        }
    }]
}
```

This approach is so close to what you want but you should know you must decode files content on the server-side by yourself, so you need more effort on the server-side.  
**Solution 2**
It's better to use `multipart/form-data` to upload files and data. Based on ["Is it possible to have a nested MultipartEntities or FormBodyPart in a multipart POST?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259989/is-it-possible-to-have-a-nested-multipartentities-or-formbodypart-in-a-multipart) question and its answer, `multipart/form-data` has a flat structure and there is no hierarchy, so you can't have desired data structure but you can still pass all of the inputs to `Api` through a single object.
According to this [article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server), you can send multiple files in a List, so if your `Api` be like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("post")
fun submitExercice(@Part data: List<MultipartBody.Part>): Call<ResponseBody>
```

then you will be able to upload multiple files. You just need to create a List of `MultipartBody.Part` and add your files to it like below:

```
list.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, fileName, RequestBody.create(mediaType, file)))
```

Now you must add the `state` parameter to this list. You can do it like this:

```
list.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("state", state))
```

I developed a class that handles all this stuff. You can use it.

```
class AnswerExerciceList(state: String) : ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>() {

    init {
        add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("state", state))
    }

    fun addFile(name: String, fileName: String, mediaType: MediaType?, file: File) {
        add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, fileName,
                RequestBody.create(mediaType, file)))
    }
}
```

You can create an instance of this class, add your files and then pass it to the `submitExercice` Api method as input.

**Update**
This answer is based on your Api documnetation. I tested my answer and the example that you mentioned in your question via `https://postman-echo.com` and result was the same. Please try the following code snippet:
**Api**

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/exercice/{id}")
fun submitExercice(@Path("id") id: Int,
                   @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
                   @Part("answer") answer: String,
                   @Part medias: List<MultipartBody.Part>,
                   @Part("state") state: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

**Media Class**

```
data class Media(val urlVidel: String, val file: File?, val mediaType: MediaType?) {
    companion object {
        fun mediaListToMultipart(mediaList: List<Media>): List<MultipartBody.Part> {
            val list = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
            for (i in mediaList.indices) {
                mediaList[i].let {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(it.urlVidel))
                        list.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("medias[$i][urlVideo]", it.urlVidel))
                    if (it.file != null) {
                        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(
                                it.mediaType,
                                it.file
                        )
                        list.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("medias[$i][file]", it.file.getName(), requestFile))
                    }
                }
            }
            return list
        }
    }
}
```

and then call Api like this:

```
ApiHelper.Instance.submitExercice(1, "Authorization Token", "Answer", Media.mediaListToMultipart(mediaList), "State").enqueue(callback)
```

Comment: I don't want to send the content of the file (base64 encoded or not) but the file directly

Comment: Did you check `solution 2`?

Comment: yes but it's not working because it's not respecting the json hierarchy :/

Comment: I added the API documentation in my question

Comment: If I apply solution 2 : Is there any way so I can add additional data such as creation_date (String) to each of the MultipartBody.Part?